# Login into moodle with another website's google sso id_token

Tags: authentication, redirect, moodle, google-sso

What if a site is already logged in with google sso and has it's sso id_token and by using of that wants to login into moodle website by bypassing it's login page. Is this achievable from Oauth2? If yes then how?

If not possible then one may have to submit the moodle login form manually which may require a decrypted password stored from db and then submit the form with it.. how it can be achievable then?

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is not possible in OpenID Connect (OIDC is the one that deals with ID tokens, not OAuth). An ID token is issued to a concrete audience (the client, or Relying Party in OIDC terms). Another client (moodle, in your case) can't use this token as it's not intended for it.

I'm not sure what you mean in the second part of your post.

Comment: Thanks Michal. In second part , i mean to say is that in Moodle to start active user session directly, it require form submission using code(JavaScript) ,which contains username and password fields, But the problem in that case is moodle applies hashing while storing password.. which do not allow to retrieve it as a plain text.

Comment: Why would you want to retrieve the password? The user is supposed to enter the password themself. You can't have access to these passwords.

Comment: Need to cross verify token data with moodle user stored in db. That makes me assured regarding user validity and then i can have manual form submission from code if i have password as plain text available.